# Log4j, maven tomcat7-maven-plugin, spring rest service

Tags: java, spring, rest, maven, tomcat

I like do test my rest service project, but it seams to be not working in the appropriate way, anyway I can fix that by my self, but i have to get the debug information for sure.
( I just see Status Code: 400 Bad Request, description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.)

Ok i used the tomcat7-maven-plugin with the following config in the pom file

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <port>9090</port>
                <httpsPort>9443</httpsPort>
                <!-- <path>/${project.build.finalName}</path> -->
                <contextFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/context.xml</contextFile>
                <keystoreFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/server.jks</keystoreFile>
                <keystorePass>123456</keystorePass>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

the log4j file resists in the /src/main/resources/ folder and will be copied in the classes folder as usual.

it looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration>

    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %d +++ P R O D +++ [%t] %c: %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org">
        <level value="error" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.springframework.web">
        <level value="DEBUG" />
    </logger>
    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

i also have a content.xml in the same folder which is needed by the plugin

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context cookies="true" >
  <!-- disable session persistence: -->
  <Manager pathname="" />
</Context>
```

I start the application with mvn clean tomcat7:run-war but the reason why the Request is not right is not printed out, there is no error at all printed.

I also tried different approaches with no luck:

- I add an ExeptionHandler to the Class with and without ResponseStatus annotation

  ```
   @ExceptionHandler
   @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
   public void handle(HttpMessageNotReadableException e) {
        logger.warn("Returning HTTP 400 Bad Request", e);
   }
  ```
- I add the log4j dependencies to the plugin config, they are in the project dependency as well, just to mention it.
- I moved the log4j.xml to the WEB-INF folder
- I started with mvn -X clean tomcat7:run-war
- I add resources config to plugin config in pom.xml file

  ```
              <resources>
                  <resource>
                      <includes>
                          <include>**/log4j.xml</include>
                      </includes>
                  </resource>
              </resources>
  ```
- I also checked the dependencies for commons-logging and slf4j and excluded them

All of these actions does not activate the logging for my rest service post call.
Ah, i used firefox restclient and curl, I also escaped the quotes in curl as I found in a different thread.

I would be also fine, if I get a different logger enabled, just to get the info whats going on in there.

Comment: error 400 must not necessarily be an error in your application. It can also be an error in the client call. For example calling with wrong or not sending the full request header. Have you captured the request header as proposed by @CodeChimp? Also, we had massive issues with a certain Antivirus and Java network traffic.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `@ExceptionHandler` only has two valid returns types:

1. A `String` indicating the view to display to the user
2. A `ModelAndView`, also setup with the proper view to display to the user

Your method seems to return void, which I do believe will make Spring ignore the exception handler all together.

As for the Bad Request, can you post what you are sending and what the REST service looks like?  You can snag the request using the Firebug plugin for FireFox.

Comment: nop, I test this, even a Value-Object is valid if you add the @ResponseBody Annotation.

Comment: BTW, I based this on the actual documentation, that states "The return type can be a String, which is interpreted as a view name or a ModelAndView object." Documentation found here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers

Answer (score 0):

Ok I guess i got it,

Fist at all,

- ExceptionHandler

  ```
  @ExceptionHandler
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
  public void handle(HttpMessageNotReadableException e) {
      logger.warn("Returning HTTP 400 Bad Request", e);
  }
  ```

should be in every REST Service class, for debug activity, if this is missing, nothing will be written in a log.

- commons-logging dependency should be available on the dependency list
- the log4j.xml or a log4j.properties in the WEB-INF or /src/main/resources is needed
- I set all logger to DEBUG, but that is not necessary for Rest debugging, it depends on the log level of ExceptionHandler. In my version WARN would be fine for getting the output

all other variations which I described in the question, are not necessary, the base version worked well after I added the ExceptionHandler in all classes.

If you like to get some more infos to the client as well, it is a good idea to follow advise 'CodeChimp' made. If you just add a String it will deliver the string named page or you can add more infos, like ModelAndView and you can even add a json or xml response, if you annotate the method with

```
@ResponseBody
```